# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 356: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: kivy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQXP7.jpg)
Its is a project of mobile app development by using library kivy.
after login in to the app there was a page which express feelings, I supposed to print feelings text like cotations which expressed by some great people.
But at that place I am getting so error like "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 356: character maps to "

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably occurring since you did not specify a file encoding on line 55 in your main.py file as shown in your screenshot image.

I would recommend adding `, encoding='utf-8'` as another parameter in your call to open. If that does not work, try another file encoding.

So to be completely clear, that line should be:

```
with open(f"quotes/{feel}.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file:
```